# pulseaudio won't detect headphone unless restarted

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

My computer is a desktop with an MSI B450m mobo. It's connected to a display via HDMI, which is also used as the main speaker. If I plug the headphone to the audio jack, I want it to switch to the headphone.

It used to work fine under Ubuntu 20.04 with Pulseaudio 13.99. After upgrading to 22.04 with Pulseaudio version 15.99, it's having weird issues:

If I unplug the headphone and plug it back in, Pulseaudio won't be able to detect the headphone anymore, it only sees the HDMI one. If I want to use the headphone again, I will have to plug in first then `pulseaudio --kill` and `pulseaudio --start`.

Is this a bug that pulseaudio cannot detect headphone unless restarted?

Edit: bluetooth headphone doesn't seem to have this problem, just the wired ones do.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to check your audio settings in the sound settings make sure that the output is set the headphone you have connected to your computer, you can also update your audio driver in device manager, you can also try a different audiojack, if none work report the problem to the Pulseaudio dev