# Changing GPU will affect WIFI and audio adapter compatibility?

Tags: drivers, wireless, sound, pulseaudio, realtek

After changing my CPU + dGPU to an APU (4600G), I noticed that several peripherals are having compatibility issues.

The wifi issue:

- Under the old setup, i had to build from the [driver](https://github.com/RinCat/RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver) after every OS update.
- Under the new setup, the OS won't recognize the adapter at all

The audio issues:

- Under the old setup, the OS won't recognize headphone unless I run `pulseaudio --kill` and `pulseaudio --start` (reported [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1460180/pulseaudio-wont-detect-headphone-unless-restarted)).
- Under the new setup, the OS can now recognize headphone once plugged in, but it doesn't recognize the HDMI (showing as dummy output) audio output any more.

Is this normal? I don't see how the GPU/CPU change would affect the peripherals especially the WIFI. Is picking hardware for Linux a lottery of compatibility or it's just Realtek that generally sucks (both chips are made by them)?

OS:

- Ubuntu 20.04

Old setup:

- AMD Ryzen 1700x
- EVGA GeForce GTX 970
- MSI B450M PRO-VDH MAX (using Realtek ALC892 audio card)
- TP-Link USB WIFI adapter (using Realtek RTL8812BU chip)

New Setup:

- AMD Ryzen 5 4600G (replacing both old CPU and GPU)
- Same mobo & WIFI adapter